# Dynamic Array pop error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to implement pop method on a dynamic array. It should copy the array to a new array with one less element. However am receiving an error instead. If I remove the code 'data[data.length] = 0;' the error disappears however the array does not change in length.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
>       at DynamicArray.pop(DynamicArray.java:37)
>       at DynamicArray.main(DynamicArray.java:55)

```
import java.util.Arrays;    

public class DynamicArray {
    private static final int SIZE_FACTOR = 5;
    private int size;
    private int index;
    private int[] data;

    public DynamicArray(int size) {
        this.data = new int[size];
    }
    public int length() {

        return size;
    }

    public int select(int k) {
        return data[k];
    }

    public void store(int o, int k) {
        data[k]=o;
    }

    public void push(int o) {
        if(data.length==size) {
            extend();
        }
        size++;
        data[index++] = o;
    }

    public int pop() {
        data[data.length] = 0;
        data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length-1);
        size--;
        return data.length;
    }

    private void extend() {
        data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length+SIZE_FACTOR);
        System.out.println("New length: " + data.length);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DynamicArray a = new DynamicArray(10);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            a.push(i);
        }
        System.out.println(a.length());
        System.out.println(a.select(99));
        a.pop();            
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's time to fire up your debugger

Comment: if I remove this line, 'data[data.length] = 0;' there is no error. however the new arrays does not return a length with one less